# knitr failed to print out system2() output

Tags: r

In R console, I can see the output from system2() by:

```
> STAR<-'/opt/NGS/STAR/STAR-2.5.2b/bin/Linux_x86_64_static/STAR'
>     system2(STAR,'--version')
STAR_2.5.2b
```

But when I have a chunk in a .Rnw file such like that:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Global STAR settings}
<<echo=TRUE, results="asis">>=
STAR<-'/opt/NGS/STAR/STAR-2.5.2b/bin/Linux_x86_64_static/STAR'
system2(STAR,'--version')
@   
\end{frame}
```

It's supposed to print out `STAR_2.5.2b` on the page but nothing was printed. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Try setting `stdout = TRUE` i.e. `system2(STAR,'--version', stdout = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! It got fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `stdout = TRUE` i.e. `system2(STAR,'--version', stdout = TRUE)`.